# Array of samplerCube

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, amd-gpu

I ran into a problem when testing a program on an AMD GPU. When tested on Nvidia and Intel HD Graphics, everything works fine. On AMD, the problem occurs precisely when trying to bind the texture. Because of this problem, the shader has no shadow maps and only a black screen is visible. Id textures and other parameters are successfully loaded. Below are the code snippets:

c++:

```
void render() {
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // start id = 10
        glUniform1i(samplersLocations[i], startId + i);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + startId + i);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texturesIds[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

glsl:

```
#version 400 core
...
uniform samplerCube shadowMaps[MAX_LAMPS_COUNT];
```

There are no errors during the compilation of shaders. As far as I understand, the texture for some reason does not bind. Depth maps themselves are drawn correctly.

**EDIT:** I access the elements of the array as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ...
    depth = texture(shadowMaps[i], fragToLight).r;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** it was found that a black screen occurs when the `samplerCube` array is larger than the bound textures. For example `MAX_LAMPS_COUNT = 2` and count = 1, then

`uniform samplerCube shadowMaps[2];`

```
glUniform1i(samplersLocations[0], startId + 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + startId + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texturesIds[0]);
```

In this case, there will be a black screen.

But if `MAX_LAMPS_COUNT = 1` (`uniform samplerCube shadowMaps[1]`) then shadows appear, but a new problem also arises:
[image]
[image]
Do not pay attention to the fact that everything is greenish, this is due to incorrect color correction settings for the video card.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** here is the complete problem area of the rendering code:

```
#define cfgtex(texture, internalformat, format, width, height) glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); \
                                                               glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalformat, width, height, 0, format, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
void render() {
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // start id = 10
        glUniform1i(samplersLocations[i], startId + i);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + startId + i);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texturesIds[i]);
    }

    renderer.mainPass(displayFB, rbo);
    cfgtex(colorTex, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA, params.scrW, params.scrH);
    cfgtex(dofTex, GL_R16F, GL_RED, params.scrW, params.scrH);
    cfgtex(normalTex, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, params.scrW, params.scrH);
    cfgtex(ssrValues, GL_RG16F, GL_RG, params.scrW, params.scrH);
    cfgtex(positionTex, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, params.scrW, params.scrH);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 1, ALGINE_RED); // dof buffer

    // view port to window size
    glViewport(0, 0, WIN_W, WIN_H);
    // updating view matrix (because camera position was changed)
    createViewMatrix();
    // sending lamps parameters to fragment shader
    sendLampsData();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cs.inPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cs.inNormal);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cs.inTexCoord);

    // drawing
    //glUniform1f(ALGINE_CS_SWITCH_NORMAL_MAPPING, 1); // with mapping
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cs.inTangent);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cs.inBitangent);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < MODELS_COUNT; i++) drawModel(models[i]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < LAMPS_COUNT; i++) drawModel(lamps[i]);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(cs.inPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(cs.inNormal);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(cs.inTexCoord);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(cs.inTangent);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(cs.inBitangent);

    ...
}
```

`renderer.mainPass` code:

```
void mainPass(GLuint displayFBO, GLuint rboBuffer) {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, displayFBO);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, params->scrW, params->scrH);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboBuffer);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

**EDIT:** It was found that indeed the entire array of samplerCube must be filled with something, otherwise there will be a black screen. Therefore, in order to avoid a black screen, all unused slots have to be filled with textures with id 0 (Is this because of the use of open source driver?). But then another problem appears - strange highlights. It was determined that they appear with the included PCF (soft shadows). Here is the problem area of the shader code:

```
const vec3 sampleOffsetDirections[20] = vec3[] (
        vec3(1, 1, 1), vec3(1, -1, 1), vec3(-1, -1, 1), vec3(-1, 1, 1),
        vec3(1, 1, -1), vec3(1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, 1, -1),
        vec3(1, 1, 0), vec3(1, -1, 0), vec3(-1, -1, 0), vec3(-1, 1, 0),
        vec3(1, 0, 1), vec3(-1, 0, 1), vec3(1, 0, -1), vec3(-1, 0, -1),
        vec3(0, 1, 1), vec3(0, -1, 1), vec3(0, -1, -1), vec3(0, 1, -1)
);

...

// get vector between fragment position and light position
vec3 fragToLight = fragWorldPos - lamps[index].lampPos;
// now get current linear depth as the length between the fragment and light position
float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);
// use the light to fragment vector to sample from the depth map
float closestDepth;

// PCF
float viewDistance = length(viewPos - fragWorldPos);
float diskRadius = (1.0 + (viewDistance / lamps[index].far)) * diskRadius_k + diskRadius_min;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    closestDepth = texture(shadowMaps[index], fragToLight + sampleOffsetDirections[i] * diskRadius).r;
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^problem here^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    closestDepth *= lamps[index].far; // Undo mapping [0;1]
    // now test for shadows
    if(currentDepth - shadow_bias > closestDepth) shadow += 1.0;
}
return shadow /= 20;
```

Any ideas? Note: everything works fine on Intel HD Graphics and Nvidia

Comment: What is `startId`? I guess that you should replace `startId + i` with just `i`.

Comment: @ybungalobill the first few slots are already taken, so I add `startId`

Comment: Just a silly taught but if on win7/8/10 check for gfx driver ... last time I check MS was enforcing their own drivers for nVidia,AMD and Intel gfx with bugged OpenGL implementation if the case download and  install driver manually from correct vendor. (but those MS drivers usually crash right after opening OpenGL context so I doubt its the case but the crash point might be also affected by used compiler/linker so its still worth to check just to be sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. For correct work, I had to fill the entire `samplerCube` array with
   zeros. Otherwise, there will be a black screen.
2. At the expense of
   glare: apparently, the problem was in the open drivers. The test was
   performed on Windows with the official drivers, and everything was
   displayed correctly, including the color correction. But the 1st
   point is not canceled.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a year or two ago with cascaded shadow maps, where it ran perfectly fine on Intel and Nvidia, but on AMD I only got the first cascade. 
Apparently, if you have plain arrays of samplers (e.g. `sampler2D tex[5]`) you need to set every element on AMD, whereas Nvidia and Intel assume it to be consecutive in memory and automatically bind all textures if you bind the first.
My solution was to use sampler arrays (e.g. `sampler2DArray`) which worked fine on every GPU.